# Can't create object from string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I've scanned many topics on this site, searched the internet, and experimented with code and nothing has worked.  Most people are using separate projects or assemblies which I am not, it's a custom class that exists in the same project and same namespace.  If I build the object manually by hard coding it in it works fine but I don't want to do that.

It's a C# ASPX project and I am debugging on IIS from Visual Studio (so maybe that's the issue?).

```
Type type = Type.GetType("<namespace>."+classname);
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(function);
response = (<cast object>)(methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null));
```

I am aiming for variable code where I can write plugins that will be dynamically instantiated.  Type.GetType always returns null.

In almost all cases type returns null or when I switch it up with other code I'll get other errors thrown about not finding file or assembly and other errors like this class just doesn't exist...

What do I have to do to be able to build an object dynamically off a string? Let's say I have a class called "Foobar" and I want to do this,

```
string classname = "Foobar";
Object foobar = new classname(); //easy in PHP, nightmare in C#
```

Any help would be great, thanks.  And before you tell me just to reference another post, I have referenced many and still have no success so if it's not the code than maybe it's how I'm debugging in a browser on IIS?

Comment: where does the `<namespace>` string come into it, or is there a variable called `namespace`?

Comment: `Object foobar = new classname(); //easy in PHP, nightmare in C#` Well, that's what `var` and/or `dynamic` keywords are for.

Comment: You might want to look into something like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) which provides a framework for writing and dynamically loading "plugins". Other options are also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the same namespace and assembly as the current object as you say, you should just be able to do the following to get hold of the `Type` you require:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(this.GetType().Namespace + "." + classname);
```

The rest should work as you have it.

Answer (score 3):

Type.GetType(String) accepts assembly-qualified type name.

See [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the type from the assembly is was defined in:

```
typeof(SomeTypeInAssembly).Assembly.GetType("Namespace.Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, final code I ended up with below from the suggestions and other post I found on this site.

```
string fullname = string.Format("{0}.{1}", this.GetType().Namespace, classname);
Type type = Type.GetType(fullname,true);
Baseclass class = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type,<parameter1>,...);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("<method>");
methodInfo.Invoke(class, null);
```

You can store the return (may need casting) if you want to deal with the return type.  Hope this helps someone if they're having issues like me.

Thanks to Rhumborl post, I guess it was an issue in just how I was originally trying to call the Type.GetType function.

Answer (score -3):

String is a native type , witch is automatically inherited from object , since every type (aka class) is an object, so there is no need to do such a thing

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Instantiating an object off a string, yes a string is an object but it's not a custom object I've created a class for.  So if I have a class Foobar, and I want to store the string foobar in a string String foobar = "Foobar", I now need to use that string to instantiate my custom object of Foobar.  Hopefully that clarifies.